# Is the build function creating new widgets to render or reusing?

Tags: flutter

I have a working snippet that I've wrote, but I kinda don't understand how flutter is (re)using the widgets creating in the build method:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyGame());
}

class MyGame extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyGame({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: GameWidget());
  }
}

class GameWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const GameWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const squareWidth = 50.0;
  static const squareHeight = 50.0;

  @override
  State<GameWidget> createState() => _GameWidgetState();
}

class _GameWidgetState extends State<GameWidget> {
  List<Offset> offsets = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (offsets.isEmpty) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        offsets.add(calculateNextOffset());
      }
    }

    List<Widget> squareWidgets = [];

    for (int j = 0; j < offsets.length; j++) {
      squareWidgets.add(AnimatedPositioned(
        left: offsets[j].dx,
        top: offsets[j].dy,
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (tapDownDetails) {
            setState(() {
              offsets.removeAt(j);
              for (int k = 0; k < offsets.length; k++) {
                offsets[k] = calculateNextOffset();
              }
            });
          },
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          child: Container(
            width: GameWidget.squareWidth,
            height: GameWidget.squareHeight,
            color: Colors.blue,

          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return Stack(
      children: squareWidgets,
    );
  }

  Offset calculateNextOffset() {
    return randomOffset(
        MediaQuery.of(context).size,
        const Size(GameWidget.squareWidth, GameWidget.squareHeight),
        MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top);
  }

  double randomNumber(double min, double max) =>
      min + Random().nextDouble() * (max - min);

  Offset randomOffset(
      Size parentSize, Size childSize, double statusBarHeight) {
    var parentWidth = parentSize.width;
    var parentHeight = parentSize.height;

    var randomPosition = Offset(
      randomNumber(parentWidth, childSize.width),
      randomNumber(statusBarHeight,parentHeight - childSize.height),
    );

    return randomPosition;
  }
}
```

Every time I click on a container, i expect my "offsets" state to be updated, but I also expect all the AnimationPositioned widgets, GestureDetector widgets and the square widgets that you see would be rerendered.

With rerendered i mean they would disappear from the screen and new ones would be rerendered (and the animation from the first widgets would be cancelled and never displayed)

However it works? Could someone explain this to me?

**EDIT: I've updated my snippet of code in my question to match what i'm asking, which i'm also going to rephrase here:**

Every time I click on a square, i want that square to disappear and all the other square to randomly animate to another position. But every time I click on a square, another random square is deleted, and the one i'm clicking is animating.

I want the square that I click on disappears and the rest will animate.

Comment: What exactly is the expected outcome of your code? I've run it in dartpad. What is the expected outcome when you click the first square that appears? Do you want it to disappear? Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of the calling object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in the corresponding subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for that State object.

Comment: Yes I want the one that you click on, disappears. Btw, your explanation answers one of my questions (about the state and reredenering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found it:

In the context of the snippet inside the question: Every time you click on a square, it will correctly remove that item, but the widgets are rerendered from that new list, and the last widget that was previously rendered will be removed instead of the one that I clicked.

This has to do because every widget in the widget tree is rendered as an element inside the element tree. If the state of the element inside the element tree is the same, it will not rerender that one. and they are all just blue squares in the end, so there is no distinction.

You can find a very nice video made by the flutter devs here:
[When to Use Keys - Flutter Widgets 101 Ep. 4](https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc)

Long story short: Here is the snippet with the fix, which is to add a Key to each widget, then the state will change on the element inside the element tree and it will rerender (and remove) the correct widgets/elements:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyGame());
}

class MyGame extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyGame({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: GameWidget());
  }
}

class GameWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const GameWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const squareWidth = 50.0;
  static const squareHeight = 50.0;

  @override
  State<GameWidget> createState() => _GameWidgetState();
}

class _GameWidgetState extends State<GameWidget> {
  List<OffsetData> offsets = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (offsets.isEmpty) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        offsets.add(OffsetData(UniqueKey(), calculateNextOffset()));
      }
    }

    List<Widget> squareWidgets = [];

    for (int j = 0; j < offsets.length; j++) {
      squareWidgets.add(AnimatedPositioned(
        key: offsets[j].key, // This line is the trick
        left: offsets[j].offset.dx,
        top: offsets[j].offset.dy,
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (tapDownDetails) {
            setState(() {
              offsets.removeAt(j);
              for (var offsetData in offsets) {
                offsetData.offset = calculateNextOffset();
              }
            });
          },
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          child: Container(
            width: GameWidget.squareWidth,
            height: GameWidget.squareHeight,
            color: Colors.blue,

          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return Stack(
      children: squareWidgets,
    );
  }

  Offset calculateNextOffset() {
    return randomOffset(
        MediaQuery.of(context).size,
        const Size(GameWidget.squareWidth, GameWidget.squareHeight),
        MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top);
  }

  double randomNumber(double min, double max) =>
      min + Random().nextDouble() * (max - min);

  Offset randomOffset(
      Size parentSize, Size childSize, double statusBarHeight) {
    var parentWidth = parentSize.width;
    var parentHeight = parentSize.height;

    var randomPosition = Offset(
      randomNumber(parentWidth, childSize.width),
      randomNumber(statusBarHeight,parentHeight - childSize.height),
    );

    return randomPosition;
  }
}

class OffsetData {
  Offset offset;
  final Key key;

  OffsetData(this.key, this.offset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up from the comments - Actually, the square you click is disappears. However, to see this visually add this to your container color:

```
color:Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
```

Now, your offsets are generating just fine and random. However, because you have an AnimatedContainer widget. This widget will remember the last x & y position of your square and animate the new square starting from that old x,y value to the new on you passed it. So if you really want the square you click on disappear - you will need to either use Positioned widget:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyGame());
}

class MyGame extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyGame({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: GameWidget());
  }
}

class GameWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const GameWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const squareWidth = 100.0;
  static const squareHeight = 100.0;

  @override
  State<GameWidget> createState() => _GameWidgetState();
}

class _GameWidgetState extends State<GameWidget> {
  List<Offset> offsets = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (offsets.isEmpty) {
      offsets.add(calculateNextOffset());
    }  
  
  
    print(offsets);
    List<Widget> squareWidgets = [];
    for (var offset in offsets) {

      squareWidgets.add(Positioned(
         left: offset.dx,
         top: offset.dy,
         //curve: Curves.easeIn,
         //duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (tapDownDetails) {
            setState(() {
              for (var i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++) {
                offsets[i] = calculateNextOffset();
              }
              offsets.add(calculateNextOffset());
              
            });
          },
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          child: Container(
            width: GameWidget.squareWidth,
            height: GameWidget.squareHeight,
            color:Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],

          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return Stack(
      children: squareWidgets,
    );
  }

  Offset calculateNextOffset() {
    return randomOffset(
        MediaQuery.of(context).size,
        const Size(GameWidget.squareWidth, GameWidget.squareHeight),
        MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top);
  }

  double randomNumber(double min, double max) =>
      min + Random().nextDouble() * (max - min);

  Offset randomOffset(
      Size parentSize, Size childSize, double statusBarHeight) {
    var parentWidth = parentSize.width;
    var parentHeight = parentSize.height;

    var randomPosition = Offset(
      randomNumber(parentWidth, childSize.width),
      randomNumber(statusBarHeight,parentHeight - childSize.height),
    );

    return randomPosition;
  }
}
```

If you want the rest of the squares to animate while only the one that is clicked disappears. You will need to rethink your implementation and track all square perhaps using unique keys and custom animations. Hope that helps!